# How do I copy a percentage of a directory into a new directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, shutil, file-copying

I am writing a function that will look like this

`def copy_file(source, training, testing, split_size):`

where:

-source is the source directory I want to copy from

-training is a directory to copy to

-testing is another directory to copy to

-split_size is the percentage of *source* i want to copy into testing and training, expressed as a decimal point (e.g. if split_size is 0.5 i will copy 50% of source to training and 50% to testing)

I am using the `shutil` library to use copy and I will iterate over my source file to copy each file, something like

```
       if len(image) > 0:
          copy(image, training)
```

But I am unsure how to specify the split_size portion of this function. I am sure this is not complicated I just have very little experience with copying files and it's my first time working with shutil.

Comment: There are a few grammatical errors in your question. Please re-read it and correct as it's hard to decipher what you're trying to do. Also more of an example would also really help as well

Comment: @Jab I couldn't find any grammatical errors, but there was an issue with formatting. it's now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os` package to get the list of the files in the source directory. Once you have the list of files, you can split the list into two list based on the percentage value passed. After that iterate through the two list to copy the files in the respective directories.

```
import os
import shutil

def copy_file(src,train,test,percent):
  files_list = os.listdir(src)
  splitVal = int(round(percent*len(file_list)))
  train_file_list = files_list[:splitVal]
  test_file_list = files_list[splitVal:]
  
  # now iterate through the two list and copy the files to respective
  # directory using shutil.copy(file_name,dest_dir)
```

Comment: oh thanks! so splitVal turns the percent into a number of files that will be copied, and then train_file_list uses that number as the slice to make the cut at?